# Pointers in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have some `NSDictionarys` full of data and I have a method which utilizes the data. Which `NSDictionary` is used depends on some input from the user, so I was wondering how I could create a pointer to the `NSDictionary` with the data.

For example

The user chooses "option foo", so the method will need to use the "foo dictionary". Instead of copying the "foo dictionary" into a temporary dictionary, how can I reference it so that "tempdictionary" has the contents of "foo dictionary" for example.

That probably made no sense, but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copying doesn't happen by default. Just grab the `NSDictionary` you want and assign it to a new pointer:

```
NSDictionary *fooDictionary = [dataDictionary valueForKey:@"foo"];
```

That will give you a pointer to the dictionary stored within `dataDictionary`. It doesn't make a copy unless you ask it to.

Answer (score 1):

The copy isn't made unless you explicitly tell the code to do so. E.g.:

```
NSDictionary *fooDict = ...; // initialize fooDict and probably other dicts

if ([self useFoo]) {
    [self stuffWithFooDict:fooDict]; // will pass pointer of fooDict
}

if ([self useFooCopy]) {
    [self stuffWithFooCopy:[fooDict copy]]; // will use a copy of fooDict
}
```